# VBA Range Validation with a coma delimited string | Run-time error '1004'

Tags: string, vba, validation, excel

I'm trying to create data validation on an entire range of cells using VBA.
I pass in a comma delimited string that is derived from a SQL query. It throws **Run-time error '1004'**. `acc` is a coma delimited String. There are no VBA keywords in the string, and the string is correct, and the SQL query is correct. This occurs at the `.Add` line.

```
With equipRange.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=acc
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

When I limit the query to only include 269 items, out of 297, it works fine. But, when I hit that item 270, it throws an exception. I don't think it has anything to do with the content.

- 268:  HP - electric energy
- 269:  HP - leaving water temp
- 270:  METER - electric energy
- 271:  METER - electric peak power

Anybody have any ideas on what is going on?

**EDIT:**
    I previously asked for a work-around, but now I want to understand how I can populate my list with my SQL query.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does `acc` look like?

Comment: acc looks like the following for 269 entries: "HP - electric energy,HP - leaving water temp"

Comment: @AtAFork, `acc` is formatted correctly. I doesn't seem to be culprit.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think, number of characters acts as limitation or is the cause for error. You should try creating a list of comma separated string.
Let's say your list of equipment comes in column A. Then, create a named range as shown below and then try to add data validation list.

Check the below sample code:

```
Sub try()

ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="List", RefersTo:="=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$8000"
Range("C2").Validation.Delete
Range("C2").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=List"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is going to be what I end up doing as a work around. But, I'd like to get my string from my SQL query, because the info can change, and I have various applications that depend on that up-to-date SQL query.